# Get the empty page before a new chapter in ConTeXt?

Tags: context, page-numbering, chapters

When starting new chapters on right-hand side, it would better make the previous page empty (no footer and header). This can be done by defining a new pagebreak and setup head,

```
\setuppagenumbering[alternative=doublesided]
\definepagebreak[chapterpagebreak][yes,header,footer,right]
\setuphead[chapter][page=chapterpagebreak]

\starttext
\startfrontmatter
\title{Preface}
\completecontent
\stopfrontmatter
\startbodymatter
\chapter{First Chapter}
\stopbodymatter
\startbackmatter
\chapter{Backmatter}
\stopbackmatter
\stoptext
```

But the page just before chapter `First Chapter` in the bodymatter will not empty, according to the wiki, we should add some setups

```
\setupsectionblock[frontpart][page=]
\setupsectionblock[bodypart] [page=]
\setupsectionblock[backpart] [page=]
```

After this, a empty page will be produced just before chapter `First Chapter` in the bodymatter and chapter `Backmatter` in the backmatter area. This method will not a perfect one, since pages in frontmatter should be numbered in lower-case Roman numerals and Arabic numerals in bodymatter. That is to say

```
\definestructureconversionset[frontpart:pagenumber][][romannumerals]
\definestructureconversionset[bodypart:pagenumber][][numbers]
```

For this requirment, the method won't work well. Maybe another method is that when the number of the last page located in the frontmatter is even, insert an empty page by using `\page[yes,empty,odd]`. Same with bodymatter and backmatter.

```
\def\emptyoddpage{%
  \ifodd\pagenumber
    \page[yes,empty,odd]
  \fi}
```

Anyone has other method to solve this problem? I think this method is from plain-TeX rather than ConTeXt, so I am expecting a ConTeXt method.

---

*Edit:* maybe what I said is unclear, let me write the codes

```
% the method from wiki
\setuppagenumbering[alternative=doublesided]
\definepagebreak[chapterpagebreak][yes,header,footer,right]
\setuphead[chapter][page=chapterpagebreak]

\definestructureconversionset[frontpart:pagenumber][][romannumerals]
\definestructureconversionset[bodypart:pagenumber][][numbers] 

\startsectionblockenvironment[bodypart]
\setcounter[userpage][1]
\stopsectionblockenvironment

\setupsectionblock[frontpart][page=]
\setupsectionblock[bodypart] [page=]
\setupsectionblock[backpart] [page=]

\starttext
\startfrontmatter
\title{Preface}
\completecontent
\stopfrontmatter
\startbodymatter
\chapter{First Chapter}
\stopbodymatter
\startbackmatter
\chapter{Backmatter}
\stopbackmatter
\stoptext
```

This code is not perfect because the page number of the Contents is Arabic numeral `1` rather that `iii`! So, I should deal with this problem by define a macro

```
% another method
\setuppagenumbering[alternative=doublesided]
\definepagebreak[chapterpagebreak][yes,header,footer,right]
\setuphead[chapter][page=chapterpagebreak]

\definestructureconversionset[frontpart:pagenumber][][romannumerals]
\definestructureconversionset[bodypart:pagenumber][][numbers] 

\startsectionblockenvironment[bodypart]
\setcounter[userpage][1]
\stopsectionblockenvironment

%\setupsectionblock[frontpart][page=]
%\setupsectionblock[bodypart] [page=]
%\setupsectionblock[backpart] [page=]

\def\emptyoddpage{%
  \ifodd\pagenumber
    \page[yes,empty,odd]
  \fi}

\starttext
\startfrontmatter
\title{Preface}
\completecontent
\emptyoddpage
\stopfrontmatter
\startbodymatter
\chapter{First Chapter}
\emptyoddpage
\stopbodymatter
\startbackmatter
\chapter{Backmatter}
\emptyoddpage
\stopbackmatter
\stoptext
```

What I want to ask is that if I don't define the `\emptyoddpage`(that's too plain-TeX), can have a ConTeXt way to solve this problem?

Comment: It's unclear to me what the actual problem is. I ran your code and I get roman page numbers in the front part, arabic ones for the body part and an empty page followed by a new chapter.

Comment: @Marco I have edited this question. Maybe it is clear now.

Comment: Can anyone explain how a mere definition of a pagebreak removes the headers/footers on the pages before chapters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set `page=yes` in the front part section block. Then the page number for the table of contents will be printed in roman numerals and continue the numbering so it becomes `iii`.

```
\setupsectionblock
  [frontpart]
  [page=yes]
```